# The type or namespace name 'FormatterContext' could not be found .net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-assembly

**My project framework : .net 4.5**
**Project Type : MVC4**
I have added System.Json of framework 4.0.
I have following code into Model -> JsonNetFormatter.cs and it's inheriting **MediaTypeFormatter** class:

```
protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<object> OnReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, System.IO.Stream stream, System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders, FormatterContext formatterContext)
        {
            var task = Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
                    {
                        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                    };

                    var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                    var jreader = new JsonTextReader(sr);

                    var ser = new JsonSerializer();
                    ser.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());

                    object val = ser.Deserialize(jreader, type);
                    return val;
                });

            return task;
        }
```

but when i am going to build solution or my project, it's throwing following error :

**The type or namespace name 'FormatterContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Am i missing any dll or because of something else, it's throwing an error?

Answer (score 0):

`FormatterContext` is removed in `MVC4` RC Version

Please refer the Release Notes:  [Release notes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes)

from : [MSDN Forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1832215.aspx)

> **Formatter improvements:** The methods on MediaTypeFormatter are now
>   public to enable unit testing of custom formatters. A single formatter
>   can now support multiple text encodings. Use 
>   BufferedMediaTypeFormatter to implement simple synchronous formatting
>   support.             FormatterContext has been removed. To get access
>   to the request from a formatter on the server implement
>   GetPerRequestFormatterInstance.

Comment: So that means i can't use "FormatterContext" into MVC4 .net 4.5? But i have changed my framework to 4.0, still it's throwing same error.

Comment: if you have changed Framework to .NET 4 then try  installing JSON.NET using nuget.

Comment: I have updated framework to 4 and updated Newtonsoft.Json.dll to 4.0's Newtonsoft.Json.dll. Now it's thworing one extra error same as above and said "The type or namespace name 'MediaTypeFormatter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @KomalJariwala: did you change your framework to .NET 4 client profile? or .NET 4?

Comment: @KomalJariwala: i think your project framework set to `.NET client profile 4.0` change it to `.NET 4.0`.