# Formatting JSON correctly with Web API Get()

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, angularjs

In my web Api project I am using parameterized methods and not calling by method name. I am using $resource in my angular code and this call works perfect.

For example this gets me a list of contacts:

```
public class LeadsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Contact> Get()
    {
        var contacts = new ContactRepository();

        return contacts.BuildContacts();
    }
}
```

The only problem I have is the casing so then I use newtonsoft and have to change the return type to string for it to work

```
public class LeadsController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        var contacts = new ContactRepository();
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contacts, Formatting.Indented, settings); 
    }
}
```

Now the issue I have is the angular is expecting an array but it is returning an object (string) so I am having errors. Here is my angular

```
return $resource('http://localhost:33651/api/Leads/', {
    get: { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
    query: {
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: true
    }
});
```

Is there a way on my web api method I can return IEnumerable and have the Json formatted in camel case correctly? What is the best way I should handle my situation?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web API already uses Newtonsoft serializer, so you need only to configure it. Add these lines to `WebApiConfig.Register` method:

```
    var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

And return `IEnumerable<Contact>` instead of the `string`, please take a look at this sample project https://github.com/maxbrodin/camel-case-serialization-webapi

**Edited**

Comment: Ok this may be a little over my head. So Im pretty sure I want to implement the last class in that blog post and use that instead of the newtonsoft class?

Comment: @osiris355 That's right, try to add `JsonNetFormatter` class and register it in `Application_Start`. This will allow you keep result of type `IEnumerable<Contact>` instead of `string`. The `OnWriteToStreamAsync` method is responsible for json output.

Comment: Im trying to make the class and am having trouble. FormatterContext wont resolve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095701/the-type-or-namespace-name-formattercontext-could-not-be-found-net-4-5

Comment: Still having some issues. If you could assist with working code I will mark answered.

Comment: @osiris355 Edited my answer, it could be done easier, please take a look at this sample project https://github.com/maxbrodin/camel-case-serialization-webapi

Comment: Thanks a ton for your demo project and assistance. I had tried that previously and it did not work which lead me to going down a deeper whole. Because of how my api project was setup the solution was this var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();  GlobalConfiguration was not working for me